# string segmentation fault when reading lines from text file

Tags: c++, string, file, text, segmentation-fault

I am getting this seg-fault when trying to read lines of a text file and put them into corresponding strings in my program.

```
if(infile.is_open()){
    //calculating the number of lines
    while(getline(infile, line)){
        numberoflines++;
    }
    //Find start of the file and start reading
    infile.clear();
    infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    if(!infile.eof()){
        //Allocate an array of strings, each string contains a line from the input file
        string STRING[numberoflines];
        int i = 0;

        while(getline(infile, STRING[i])){

            cout<<STRING[i]<<endl;
            i++;
        }
    }

    infile.close();
}
```

The program actually prints out every single line, yet terminated with a seg-fault when larger text file is provided.

Comment: what is `STRING`? Why are you calling a variable `STRING`?

Comment: What is *larger*? Is the number of lines greater than `numberoflines` in your program?

Comment: I smell a stackoverflow, use `std::vector<std::string> lines(numberoflines);`

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant Because he likes, just for that ! should he ask the forum for a meaning full name ?

Comment: Is numberoflines initialized as 0 ? Where ?

Comment: C++ doesn't have dynamically sized built-in arrays. If your code compiles, it is using an extension. You are best off using `std::vector<std::string>` and just adding strings using `push_back(line)`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I do understand your point, it's just for the sake of argument, I understand it's not the best programming practice, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis numberoflines is initialized as zero just outside the if-statement in the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be reading the file twice (once for the number of lines and once for the lines themselves).  As suggested by others, using a std::vector is well suited.  Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2 )
        return 1;
    std::vector< std::string > lines;
    std::ifstream infile( argv[1] );
    if( infile.is_open() )
    {
        std::string buffer;
        while( std::getline( infile, buffer ).good() ) 
            lines.push_back( buffer );
        inflie.close();
    }
    size_t numberoflines = lines.size();

    std::ostream_iterator< std::string > out( std::cout, "\n" );
    std::copy( lines.begin(), lines.end(), out );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I am no pro-programmer, havn't learned about vector. Just wondering how to access each individual string if you actually implement this. Much appreciated again!

Comment: Sure.  Like an the array, you can access each element with the subscript operator [ that the class overloads.  So you would do lines[0] for the first, lines[1] for the second, etc.  lines.size() returns the length of the vector (0 for empty).  You can iterate by going:
for( size_t index = 0; index < lines.size(); ++index )
    lines[index];
or by iterator:
for( std::vector< std::string >::iterator iter( lines.begin() ); iter != lines.end(); ++iter )
    *iter;